# How To set timezone in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

How To set timezone in cakephp ? So that default timezone should be use anywhere in the setup.

```
date_default_timezone_set();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**add this code in core.php go to app/config/core.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
```